# Determine if we run under AWS Lambda + Zappa?

Tags: aws-lambda, zappa

Is there a way to determine if we run under AWS Lambda + Zappa? Maybe some environment variable? (I want to load different settings if my Python app starts under Zappa.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can check a variable from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables such as `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT`.